# Объясните пожалуйста это выражение. После указания параметров функции стоит двоеточие и тип данных

Tags: php

То что присвоено массиву значения понятно а вот двоеточие  и bool  к чему здесь?

```
curl_setopt_array(CurlHandle $handle, array $options): bool
```

Объясните пожалуйста это выражение. После  указания параметров функции стоит двоеточие и тип данных

Comment: Только curl_setopt_array - это не массив, а функция

Comment: RTFM батенька  :)

Answer (score 1):

> двоеточие и bool к чему здесь

Это тип данных, которые возвращает функция или метод.

В данном случае функция возвращает значение булева типа: `true`, если все параметры были успешно установлены, и `false` - если нет.

Таким образом мы сообщаем РНР, что эта функция не должна возвращать ничего, кроме булевых значений. И теперь, если функция вдруг вернет что-то другое, то РНР выдаст ошибку.

Это работает точно так же как объявление типов для параметров, только для возвращаемых значений.

Comment: то есть получается что мы указываем выражению вернуть нам булево после выполнения, правильно?

Comment: Это указывает на то, что фунция/метод возвращает булев тип............не "выражению", а "функции/методу"

Comment: @Иван нет. Никаких выражений тут нет. Мы говорим РНР, что эта функция не должна возвращать ничего, кроме булевых значений. И теперь, если функция вдруг вернет что-то другое, то РНР выдаст ошибку.